# Why lambda expression threw this error?

Tags: java, lambda

When a started my jetty server, it throws this error:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [WARNING]  [WARNING] Some problems
>   were encountered while building the effective model for
>   br.com.governa.ponto:governa-ponto-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
>   'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be
>   unique: br.com.governa.admin:governa-admin-persistencia:jar ->
>   duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 32, column 15 [WARNING]
>   'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be
>   unique: org.springframework:spring-web:jar -> duplicate declaration of
>   version (?) @ line 147, column 15 [WARNING]  [WARNING] It is highly
>   recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability
>   of your build. [WARNING]  [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven
>   versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
>   [WARNING]  [INFO]  [INFO] Using the builder
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder
>   with a thread count of 1 [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building governa-ponto-web Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:9.0.5.v20130815:start
>   (default-cli) @ governa-ponto-web >>> [INFO]  [INFO] <<<
>   jetty-maven-plugin:9.0.5.v20130815:start (default-cli) @
>   governa-ponto-web <<< [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   jetty-maven-plugin:9.0.5.v20130815:start (default-cli) @
>   governa-ponto-web --- [INFO] Configuring Jetty for project:
>   governa-ponto-web Maven Webapp [INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set.
>   Defaulting to
>   /home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/main/webapp
>   [INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic [INFO] Classes =
>   /home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/target/classes
>   [INFO] Configuring Jetty from xml configuration file =
>   /home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/test/resources/jetty.xml
>   [INFO] Configuring Jetty from xml configuration file =
>   /home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/test/resources/jetty-ssl.xml
>   [INFO] Configuring Jetty from xml configuration file =
>   /home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/test/resources/jetty-https.xml
>   [INFO] Context path = /governa-ponto-web [INFO] Tmp directory =
>   /home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/target/tmp
>   [INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml [INFO]
>   Web overrides =  none [INFO] web.xml file =
>   file:/home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
>   [INFO] Webapp directory =
>   /home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/main/webapp
>   [INFO] jetty-9.0.5.v20130815 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found
>   for logger (com.mchange.v2.log.MLog). log4j:WARN Please initialize the
>   log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   [INFO] No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one,
>   please configure one. [WARNING] EXCEPTION 
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 22502   at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:986)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:781)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:769)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:769)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:769)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:769)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:769)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:769)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.MavenAnnotationConfiguration.doParse(MavenAnnotationConfiguration.java:91)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.MavenAnnotationConfiguration.parseWebInfClasses(MavenAnnotationConfiguration.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:122)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:464)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1317)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:731)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:280)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:563)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:359)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   [INFO] No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
>   [INFO] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext May 08, 2015
>   12:12:03 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
>   INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.10 ( 20150205-0906
>   https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.10@14334) for context
>   '/governa-ponto-web' May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance INFO:
>   JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans
>   methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations
>   processed. May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 18 at position 47
>   May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 48
>   May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 49
>   May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 50
>   May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool -17 at position
>   51 May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 15 at position
>   239 May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 76 at position
>   242 May 08, 2015 12:12:06 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation SEVERE: Unknow type constant pool 16 at position
>   243 May 08, 2015 12:12:08 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor
>    INFO: Monitoring
>   file:/home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
>   for modifications May 08, 2015 12:12:08 PM
>   org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener
>   processEvent INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.1 May 08, 2015 12:12:08 PM
>   org.primefaces.extensions.application.PostConstructApplicationEventListener
>   processEvent INFO: Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 3.0.0 [INFO] Set
>   web app root system property: 'webapp.root' =
>   [/home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/main/webapp]
>   [INFO] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'rest' [INFO] Started
>   o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@1ee27d73{/governa-ponto-web,[file:/home/vinicius/projetos/GerenciadorPonto/Fontes/trunk/governa-ponto-all/governa-ponto-web/src/main/webapp/,
>   jar:file:/home/vinic
>   ius/.m2/repository/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.2.10/jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar!/META-INF/resources/,
>   jar:file:/home/vinicius/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.1/primefaces-5.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/,
>   jar:f
>   ile:/home/vinicius/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/extensions/primefaces-extensions/3.0.0/primefaces-extensions-3.0.0.jar!/META-INF/resources/,
>   jar:file:/home/vinicius/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/themes/all
>   -themes/1.0.10/all-themes-1.0.10.jar!/META-INF/resources/],AVAILABLE}{/governa-ponto-web.war}
>   [WARNING] !RequestLog [INFO] Started
>   ServerConnector@3da7772b{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443} [INFO] Started
>   Jetty Server

My lambda code:

```
List<HorarioDetalhe> horarioDetalheLista = new ArrayList<HorarioDetalhe>();
horarioDetalheLista.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                        new HorarioDetalhe(DiaDaSemanaEnum.SEG),
                        new HorarioDetalhe(DiaDaSemanaEnum.TER), 
                        new HorarioDetalhe(DiaDaSemanaEnum.QUA), 
                        new HorarioDetalhe(DiaDaSemanaEnum.QUI),
                        new HorarioDetalhe(DiaDaSemanaEnum.SEX),
                        new HorarioDetalhe(DiaDaSemanaEnum.SAB),
                        new HorarioDetalhe(DiaDaSemanaEnum.DOM)));
horarioDetalheList = horarioDetalheLista.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(HorarioDetalhe::getDiaSemana ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: please post the full exception

Comment: Your lambda code has several lines. In which one the error occurs?

Comment: The error probably has nothing to do with your code. It's thrown in org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader. You're probably using a version of jetty that doesn't support Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

The version of my Jetty was old, i have changed to 9.2.0.v20140526 and it works