# Strange fatal errors with 'JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner' on web application startup

Tags: jsf-2, jetty

I get some strange fatal errors when I start up my web application since I upgraded it to Java 8. Here is an example of the messages (and there a lot of them):

> Nov 08, 2016 4:11:08 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo
>   containsAnnotation FATAL: Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 126

The application was running a Jetty (quite old, 8.1.14.v20131031) before. Than these fatal errors appeared and I found this question [Why lambda expression threw this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126975/why-lambda-expression-threw-this-error), so I changed the Jetty to 9.2.9.v20150224. The fatal errors are still here, but the other post indicates it has something to do with lambdas in faces components like converters. Maybe the javax-faces are to old? I updated from 2.1.9 to 2.2.9, but the messages are still here.

Have somebody I hint for me?

Best regards,
Felix

Comment: The bytecode scanner error is JSF specific, Jetty is not involved, so changing versions of Jetty will have no effect on your results.  The real question is: Which javax-faces supports java 8?

Comment: You are right, it is javax-faces. I tried out version 2.3.0-m6 and the error messages were gone. Sadly the rest of my application need some migration work.